# What's the difference between joda yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ and ISO (wiki) date format?

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime, iso

The format string of [Joda ISO](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTime()) date is:

`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ`

the format string defined like in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC) is:

`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Is there a difference or just a wrong documentation at Joda?

Comment: I cannot find the string `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` on that wiki page.

Comment: @Duncan the box besides _Time zone designators_ describes only last part of the pattern

Comment: Can you quote the part that suggests `Z` should be used in Java?

Comment: @Duncan you are right. It's confusing, because I have a problem in elasticsearch with that. It doesn't work with java, but the same json created with java works with the javascript console sense. And, if you want a DateTime coming from postgres without timezone it could have a `Z` in the time-string not in the pattern.

Comment: there is a third one: `"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`
this pattern creates an ISO date in a format that [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) is using as default

Comment: what is SSS in that time format?

Comment: from http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html : S = fraction of second, in this example with 3 digits = 1/1000 fraction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Joda [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html):

> 'Z' outputs offset without a colon, 'ZZ' outputs the offset with a colon

[AFAIK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) in ISO 8601 format timezone designator colon is optional and both variants (+04:00 and +0400) are allowed

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia format is incorrect. Joda's is correct. If you use the extended datetime format, timezone offset must be extended too. So, a single `Z` is simply wrong.

It must be either `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ` or `yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSZ`.